# How to use code from one class in another C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to link a random seating code to my User Interface class and I am stumped on how I could call upon this at anytime through my user interface. The below is currently kept inside a `FirstClassCarriage` class.

```
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        bool[] seats = new bool[32];
        //To keep a separate list of seats taken          
        List<int> seatsBooked = new List<int>();
        bool quit = false;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            //int seatAssignFirstClass = rand.Next(0, 32);-> Moved to switch-case 1: block
            int seatAssignThirdClass = rand.Next(32);

                    int seatAssignFirstClass; //Variable moved from main loop
                    //Are there any seats booked already or this is the first?
                    if (seatsBooked.Count == 0) //if this is the first seat to be booked...
                    {
                        seatAssignFirstClass = rand.Next(0, 32);
                        seats[seatAssignFirstClass] = true;
                        seatsBooked.Add(seatAssignFirstClass);  //Add seat to the list of booked seats.                            
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        do //while there are available seats and current seat has not being assigned before.
                        {
                            seatAssignFirstClass = rand.Next(0, 32);
                            if (!seatsBooked.Contains(seatAssignFirstClass)) //if seatAssignFirstClass is not booked.
                            {
                                seats[seatAssignFirstClass] = true;

                            }
                            //repeat while the random seat number is already booked and there are  avaialable seats
                        } while (seatsBooked.Contains(seatAssignFirstClass) && seatsBooked.Count < 32);
                        //IMPORTANT: Number on line bellow needs tos be one bigger than rest
                        if (seatsBooked.Count < 34) //if seatsBooked list is not full for First Class
                        {
                            seatsBooked.Add(seatAssignFirstClass); //Add current random-generated seat to the list.
                        }

                    }
                    //IMPORTANT: Number on line bellow needs tos be one bigger than rest
                    if (seatsBooked.Count >= 34) //If all seats are booked
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("All seats for First Class are booked");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");

                    }
                    else //Give customer their seat nmumber
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Train seat number: {0}", seatAssignFirstClass + 1);
                        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue to the main menu...");

                    }

        } while (!quit);
```

Comment: All that your code seems to do is randomly shuffle the numbers `0` to `31` in the `List<int> seatsBooked` variable. You can do that by this if you wanted to `List<int> seatsBooked = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToList();`. Much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest unit of code reuse in C# is a function.  You need to put this code in a function, and then you can call it from other places.  Easiest would be for that to be a `public static` function, but as you learn more about design you may find that there are better ways of sharing the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to classes in other files with the `using` keyword and the desired class' `namespace`

Example:

```
namespace MyProject.MyCore {
    public class MyClass {
        public void MyMethod() { }
    }
}
```

You would then refer to this namespace in the calling class, like so:

`using MyProject.MyCore`

Which allows you to instantiate the class object, like so:

`var myInstantiatedClass = new MyClass();`

And call it's method like so:

`myInstantiatedClass.MyMethod();`

Methods can also be marked static, which removes the need to instantiate the class, and would be called instead using the Type.Method() syntax, like `MyClass.MyMethod()`.

You can also forgo adding a reference by using a fully qualified path.

`var myInstantiatedClass = new MyProject.MyCore.MyClass()`

Of course, if this code is in a different project, or assembly, you'll have to add a reference to the project or binary to gain access to the types it provides.

Answer (score 0):

[This example may be your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561419/5737223)

Or you can use static methods like

```
namespace MyProject.MyCore {
    public class MyClass {
        public static void MyMethod() { }
    }
}
```

And you can use this method from another class

```
MyProject.MyCore.MyClass.MyMethod();
```